# why does console.log(document.body) give different looking result?

Tags: javascript, dom

I embedded `console.log(document.body)` at my local page for learning purpose and when I hit refresh it displayed properties of body element like baseURL, innerHTML, etc... rather than its 
content. Why is this happening? (I am using Chrome43)

Comment: What do you mean by "property of body"? What do you think `typeof document.body` would be?

Comment: Object for both situations, It showed me things like innerHTML, baseURL and etc rather than the usual DOM tree

Comment: There is no specification for what the console should do, so what you see is whatever the browser developer thought would be useful. If you want to see the content, use the *innerHTML* property.

Comment: It's a feature of Chrome.  When you log elements, the element shows.

Comment: i tried `console.log(document.body)` and it logged the `<body>` tags and everything between them, Using Chrome `Version 44.0.2403.155 m` .. I would prefer to see all the methods of the `body` object though...

Comment: Thanks I was just curious why it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript and the DOM, `document.body` is an object, and when you log it with console, Chrome is displaying displaying the object, which includes all of its properties. The content of `document.body` can be found in the `innerHTML` property and accessible via other properties as well.

Chrome may be displaying the object properties instead of the DOM tree if there's a race condition and `console.log(document.body)` is fired prior to the completion of the DOM tree.

If you need the DOM tree, then try logging `document.body` after the body loads.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if the reverse is desired you can use `console.dir` (i.e. to list properties instead of the string representation of the dom object)

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is the root of the DOM, not the same as `window`, the global browser scope.  `console.log(document.body);` logs the DOM element, not the JavaScript object.

Comment: If `document` is the root of the DOM, what then is `document.documentElement`? Also, the “DOM element” and the “JavaScript object” are the same, DOM nodes are just _presented_ in a special way in the console.

Comment: @Xufox It's dumbed down a bit, sure.  But how do *you* explain `document === window; // false`?

Comment: They are not the same objects. Not sure what you’re asking. `window` is a `Window` and `document` is a `Document`. They have different purposes.

Comment: @Xufox - Just responding to - the “DOM element” and the “JavaScript object” are the same

Comment: Oh, yeah, for JavaScript there’s no real distinction between `document.body` as a DOM element and as a JS object. Or did you mean something different?